# How TFS setup in visual studio 2019

Tags: tfs

How to setup TFS in visual studio 2019 With step by step

I try many way but not worked properly. And how to work it.please inform me step by step.
Please help regarding this issues and help me. Any link?. Provide any link or site they give step by step solution.

Answer (score 0):

By "setup" I'm assuming you mean connecting to Azure DevOps (aka TFS) from Visual Studio.

Azure DevOps has a cloud version (Azure DevOps Services) and an on-premise version (Azure DevOps Server). Which are you connecting to?

Officially,

- see [Azure DevOps Servies - Connect from Visual Studio or Team Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/connect-to-projects?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fget-started%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2019#connect-from-visual-studio-or-team-explorer) for the cloud version and
- see [Azure DevOps Servies - Connect from Visual Studio or Team Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/connect-to-projects?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fget-started%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops-2022&tabs=visual-studio-2019#connect-from-visual-studio-or-team-explorer) for the on-premise version.

But as of the time of this post the content is the same.

The cloud version is generally linked to the Microsoft account that is also linked to your Visual Studio license. From the "File" menu choose "Account Settings..." and verify that your Microsoft account has been added to Visual Studio. The "Connect to a Project" window should show the cloud instances your Microsoft account has access to.

For an on-premise server, you need to click the "Add Azure DevOps Server" link in the "Connect to a Project" window and manually enter the URL for the on-premise server.